# Passing Variables to Class Attributes

Tags: python, class

I've two files, one of which is a python (2.7) file with a class defined. I know how to create instances and the differences between class attributes and instance attributes. I know that upon creation of any instance, you pass variables based on what's defined in the constructor. But I'd like to pass a variable from the other file into my python file as a class attribute, not an instance attribute. Is this possible?

File #1 (Python 2.7):

```
class Controller:

"""
counter is my desired class attribute. But here, python
tells me GRID is not defined.
"""
counter = (GRID ** 2)  # Gives a NameError.

def __init__(self, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GRID):
    """I'd like GRID to be a variable that's read from another file."""
    self.WIDTH = WIDTH
    self.HEIGHT = HEIGHT
    self.GRID = GRID
```

File #2 ("Master" file to hold all constants and magic numbers):

```
WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500
GRID = 4
controller = Controller(WIDTH, HEIGHT, GRID)  # New Controller object.
```

When I try to define `counter` as a formula based on variable `GRID`, I get a `NameError: GRID is not defined`. Is there a way that I can define a class attribute -- `counter` in this case -- in terms of a variable?

Obviously I could just write `counter = 4 ** 2`, but I'd like to keep all constants and magic numbers in a single file, so I can update them only in one file as necessary.

Comment: It makes no sense to take GRID as parameter, when at the same time it’s supposed to be a predefined constant. Define counter to be an INSTANCE variable instead and be happy.

Comment: You just need an `import` statement to use a constant in another module

Comment: @deets Well I've other files (.py modules) that need to read the same exact `counter` -- like a global variable, so if I put `counter` as an instance attribute, how can other modules read/write the same `counter`? Wouldn't there be separate `counter` instances in every module, every time I create a `Controller` object in my other modules?

Comment: Then pass the one object around.